# Setting height and width not function in dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am new to jQuery and I am trying to use the dialog function. 
When I am looking at the demo (animated.html) provided with the jquery.ui, I have tried to insert an huge image inside the dialog box.

It works well when inserting the following code, it restricted the size of dialog box.

However when I removed the stylesheet (jquery.ui.all.css and demos.css) ref from the demo, the dialog box now are not under restriction and show the whole image without scroll bar in the dialog box. 
(And hence the parent contain scroll bar now, which is not favorable)

Which subject in style sheet enable to set the size of dialog box?

For the first time:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
<script src="../../jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.button.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.effect.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.effect-blind.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.effect-fade.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.effect-explode.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../demos.css">

<script>
$(function() {
   $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: {
  effect: "fade",
  duration: 1000
        },
    hide: {
  effect: "explode",
      duration: 1000
     },
    maxWidth:400,
    maxHeight: 300,
    width: 400,
    height: 300,

});

$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
});
</script>
```

For the second time:

```
<script src="../../jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.button.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.effect.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.effect-blind.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.effect-fade.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.effect-explode.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: {
            effect: "fade",
            duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 1000
        },
              maxWidth:400,
    maxHeight: 300,
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    overflow: 'auto',
    });

    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: i'm confused. i can guess actual dialog invocation is occurred in the second one where you didn't pass any options that you've done for first one.

Comment: When looking at the jquery.ui.dialog.css, there are just some styling in the toolbar and etc, and would css affect much for the js?

Comment: please put your code in jsfiddle.